# Proof of equivalence of definitions for a vertex of a polyhedron

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, polyhedra

In [these](http://www.princeton.edu/~aaa/Public/Teaching/ORF363_COS323/F16/ORF363_COS323_F16_Lec11.pdf) lecture slides from Princeton University I found the following definition of a vertex of a (convex) polyhedron (p. 11).

> A point $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vertex of a polyhedron $P$ if
>
> 1) $x\in P$
>
> 2) $\exists n$ linearly independent constraints that are tight at $x$

The definition I am familiar with of a vertex is a face (intersection of $P$ with a supporting hyperplane) of cardinality one.

Can anyone refer me to a proof of the equivalence of these definitions?

Comment: What exactly is a "supporting hyperplane" according to your definition?

Comment: @DavidK A supporting hyperplane for a plyhedron $P$ is a hyperplane for which $P$ resides completely in one of the halfspaces induced by the hyperplane.

Comment: I would say that the definition in the lecture is more common than your definition, which exploits a property of vertices of convex polyhedra, but does not describe them as we normally think of them. Though the wording is not what I am used to, once you interpret it, it is exactly the normal concept: the common point of contact of a collection of faces, whose intersection is exactly one point.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sure. In the picture I have in my head of polyhedra in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ these two definitions are easily interchangeable. I was rather referring to a formal proof of equivalence

Comment: I don't have a formal proof to point you to. But to prove your version, take an average normal direction for the hyperplanes ("constraints"), and have your supporting hyperplane normal to that. To prove this from yours, take the set of all supporting hyperplane defining this vertex, and show that in the limit they provide $n$ independent constraints that are "tight" at the vertex.